# IF statement not working correctly/to specified output

Tags: c

I am trying to use an `if` statement.

- I am doing a time counter which counts the amount of Months in a year - so if its '11 Months',Year would be 0. So 37 Months would be '3 Years' '1 Month'.
- Once the 'MonthlyDuration' hits 13 then '1 Year' '1 month' would appear.
- So every 13 months 1 would be added to the year counter and the month counter would reset.

  ```
  if (MonthlyDuration = 13);
   Year += 1;  
  if (MonthlyDuration != 13);
  Year += 0;

  printf("\n\r %4.d", Year, MonthlyDuration);
  ```
- It would then be added to the end of a print statement as you can see above.

  - Anybody have any idea to why this is not working properly?

Comment: `MonthlyDuration = 13`->`MonthlyDuration == 13`

Comment: `if (MonthlyDuration = 13);` <- remove that semicolon!

Comment: Actually it's rather: `if (MonthlyDuration = 13);` -> `if (MonthlyDuration == 13)` (watch out for the removed semicolon) and `if (MonthlyDuration != 13)` -> `else`

Answer (score 1):

1. Lose the semicolons at the end of your `if`s.
2. You're using a single `=`, which is assignment.  You need to use two (`==`) to test for equality.
3. While not required for single statement `if`s, you may want to include braces.

Corrected code looks like this:

```
if (MonthlyDuration == 13) {
    Year += 1;
}
if (MonthlyDuration != 13) {
    Year += 0;
}
```

Comment: the second `if` can be replaced by an `else`. if `MonthlyDuration` is not equal to 13 then it it pointless to test if it is different from 13. You can even drop it, because `Year += 0` has no side effect at all.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thought about that, but wasn't sure it was worth putting it in the answer (there are other things I'd change as well). I'm happy to bow to peer pressure if enough people think it's worthwhile.

Comment: That works to the point counting the amount of months in a year.
The only issue now is that it is meant ot Add '1' to the year for every 12 months that pass.

Comment: @Morph - Try working on that yourself (I know it's frustrating, but you'll learn more struggling and figuring it out than having it handed to you--I speak from personal experience). If you run into issues, open another question with your code, everything you've tried, and what the symptoms are.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(MonthlyDuration = 13)
```

with

```
if(MonthlyDuration == 13)
```

A `=` assigns a value. You need a `==` to compare a value.
Also, remove the semicolons at the end of the if statement.
Or
just use this code to get the program you want

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numMonths;
int years = 0;
cout << "Enter the number of months " << endl;
cin >> numMonths;
if(numMonths > 12)
years = numMonths / 12;
cout << (numMonths - (years * 12)) <<" months and " << years << " years. " 
<< endl;
return 0;

 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should follow the TAGs too and not just the QUESTION. There is no `cout << << endl` and `cin` in `C`